# Ring volume keeps reseting to zero

Tags: ringtone, oneplus-x

I have a OnePlus X running Android 5.1.1.

I noticed that the ring volume keeps reseting itself (or is reset by s.t.) to zero. This usually happens when I switch the phone back from no-interruptions mode but also at essentially random moments (if much more rarely then).

Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: Same issue with my samsung galaxy `S5 Android 5.0`

Comment: Same here too, though for some reason (ROM bug?) I can tilt to control it.

Comment: Like tilt the phone??

Answer (score 1):

My Problem is Solved by upgrading Android lollipop to `marshmallow 6.0.1`.

Comment: For me the problem was not remedied by an update to 6.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Many users claim that turning off *Settings > Device > Call > Increase Volume in Pocket* resolves this problem.

Comment: I have no "Call" setting under "Device".