# Ringtone volume automatic set to zero in Samsung Galaxy S5

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, volume-control

I am using Samsung Galaxy `S5 SM-G00H Android 5.0`. It's ringing volume set to zero after restarting it. Does anyone have solution for this issue?

Comment: Related: [Ring volume keeps reseting to zero](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/150721/16575)

Comment: @Izzy  but there were no solution for it.

Comment: I didn't claim that :) Just linking the two together so as soon as a solution pops up for one it can be found from the other ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Problem is Solved by upgrading Android lollipop to `marshmallow 6.0.1`.